# Unable to use declval in typeid for TDM-GCC

Tags: c++, c++14, typeid, tdm-gcc

Compiler: TDM-GCC-5.1.0 (SJLJ unwinding)

I was playing around with `declval` and I noticed that I was unable to use it in a context where it should work: as an argument to `typeid()`.

In the following code, I use `declval` for one of it's primary use cases: to obtain the return type of a method without going through an instance. The error I get is the static_assert message of `declval`, but that should be impossible because `typeid()` doesn't evaluate it's argument in this case:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>

struct Foo
{
    int func();
};

int main()
{
    typeid(std::declval<Foo>().func());
}
```

This doesn't compile for me (when compiled with `-std=c++14`). My only guess is that either I've found a compiler bug, or I've done something obviously wrong and I can't see it. If it is the latter, my apologies.

EDIT:
Thanks to ildjarn for helping me out, the solution is to use `decltype`, so the last line of code becomes:

```
typeid(decltype(std::declval<Foo>().func()));
```

and this works nicely. However, now my question becomes: how come? Both `typeid()` and `decltype()` are unevaluated contexts, so I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Try `typeid(decltype(std::declval<Foo>().func()));`

Comment: Ah, that works! Wonder why that is though...

Comment: From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid): "If `expression` is not a glvalue expression of polymorphic type, `typeid` does not evaluate the expression[.]". I'm thinking compiler bug.

Comment: @Quentin : Yup – "*If expression is not a glvalue expression of polymorphic type, `typeid` does not evaluate the expression, and the `std::type_info` object it identifies represents the static type of the expression.*" Exactly as does `decltype`, which fixes it.

Comment: @ildjarn I'm not sure what you're saying. Using `decltype` calls the other version of `typeid` (labeled "(1)" in cppreference). But "version 2" should also work as-is, since it does not evaluate its argument.

Comment: @Quentin : That's _exactly_ what I'm saying – using `decltype`, which works, should be semantically identical to "version 2", which doesn't. "Yup"  meaning "yup, definitely compiler bug."

Comment: @ildjarn, so it IS a bug. Well, I think I'll answer the question now

Comment: @ildjarn my bad ! Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Do note that there are situations where `typeid` will evaluate its parameter by design, namely when used with polymorphic types.  It may be best to wrap `declval` in `decltype` whenever using `typeid`, to guarantee an unevaluated context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a compiler bug.

The solution around it is to use `decltype()` around the expression. Both `decltype()` and `typeid()` (in this case of a non-polymorphic-glvalue expression) are unevaluated contexts, which shouldn't make a difference, which is what makes this a bug. Using `decltype()` here acts as a sort of "unevaluated context buffer", and somehow `typeid()` likes this better.

<s>Well, time to contact TDM about this.</s> This bug isn't TDM's issue, it's a vanilla bug (thanks ildjarn).

Comment: This bug [repros on upstream GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b9b51852babf848), albeit with a different manifestation. It would appear that the compiler is trying to evaluate `std::declval` thus causing an error before it's decided it's operating in an unevaluated context, which wouldn't have caused the error. (Ahh, I love C++.) In any case, I don't think TDM has any part to play here.